# Angular passing parameters to css animation

Tags: css, angular, typescript

For the animation CSS code above, I'm wondering whether there's any way to pass the values of borderColor and width as parameter from TypeScript.

CSS Code

```
.app-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 8px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: app-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Html Code

```
<div class="app-iconDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: No.  You should instead override the css parameters at runtime using Angular css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with `ngStyle` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)).

So for example if you want to style a `div` element according to your CSS with a `borderColor` variable from your Angular Component, this is your code:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'border-color': borderColor + ' transparent transparent transparent'}"></div>
```

If there are many styles to apply, you can also create an object in the TypeScript class and reference this object in the `ngStyle` directive.

HTML:

```
<div [ngStyle]="myStyle"></div>
```

TS:

```
this.myStyle = {
  'border-color': this.borderColor + ' transparent transparent transparent',
  // ...
}
```

Comment: But the style of the content is a lot, can not be written in ngstyle. Is there any other way?